# Where do I find messages regarding last failed Linux boot?

Tags: boot, logs

My Linux boot fails often. I have removed `quiet` from my boot options so I can see what's going on. Basically after showing a bunch of [pass] messages, it hangs. It does not hang *every* time. Now I know dmesg is the way I can see boot messages.

But I want to look at the boot messages of the previous boot and not the current boot (because this one booted normally, while last one hanged).

Also are there any other logs I can look at to find the problem? I am using Ubuntu Natty 11.04. Should I recompile my kernel with debugging support? Is that the only way to debug this issue?

Finally, is this what is called a kernel panic (soft / hard or something)?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**`/var/log/messages`** (or **`/var/log/syslog`** on some systems) is the main system log file - look there. Depending on configuration options, it can contain same, more or less information than `dmesg` shows. Also, it is continuous by default (appended, not replaced at each boot).

Whether or not you'll need to recompile your kernel to solve the problem depends on what you can already find there and in other app-specific logs.

**Kernel panic** is a symptom of a serious system problem. So serious that the kernel is not equipped with means to go about it. This can be triggered by many various issues of various kinds: including driver bugs, severe hardware failures, bugs in base system programs, rarely userspace applications.

Comment: In my installation the file was called syslog and not messages in the folder /var/log. I have found the message : could not open output file /dev/xconsole before every hang of the kernel.

Comment: Ok, thanks for telling about `syslog` alternative name. Added to the answer for reference. I hope you managed to solve the problem.

Comment: /var/log/syslog and /var/log/messages are not the same file, and one should not under normal circumstances exist without the other. They're both generated by the syslog daemon(like rsyslog). Usually *syslog* will contain most if not all messages, whereas *messages* will be more filtered. See your syslog config (probably /etc/rsyslog.conf) for more details.

Comment: @gamen Not exactly. This depends on the **program** that handles system messages (logger daemon). Your description and the files you refer to indicate that your system uses **`rsyslog`**. Another popular one is **`syslog-ng`**. But in each case, the exact file names and their roles depend on the configuration. So there are no general "normal circumstances" and `/var/log/messages` can be, and often is, the main system log.

Comment: @roz yes, by finding the message before system crashed in syslog and searching for a solution on google, I managed to solve the problem

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Thanks for being more specific. It would be interesting if you could give examples of default configurations which do not generate both files regardless of the syslog daemon running. I can only think of non-linux systems exhibiting this behavior out of the box (FreeBSD for example), but if you have any (particularly linux distributions and/or system logger default configurations), I'd love to know!

Comment: @gamen I'm afraid don't understand what you mean by *default configurations which do not generate both files regardless of the syslog daemon running*. I'm using `syslog-ng` on gentoo and it uses `/var/log/messages` only by default. If you'd like to know what systems use similar default configuration, you can download the source package and have a look at various `syslog-ng.conf` files prepared to be shipped for particular systems.

Comment: @gamen ...My quick search in the said sources revealed (to name only linuxes) Fedora, Red Hat and Debian to use `/var/log/messages` and not `/var/log/syslog`. Other than this, I can see that the minimal `syslogd` built into `busybox` uses `/var/log/messages` by default as well. Another interesting way to research this topic is to google for "Linux log files".