# Configure systemd-journal-gateway on CentOS7

Tags: centos, systemd, systemd-journald

I installed `systemd-journal-gatewayd` on CentOS7 and started it. If I connect to the given port the HTTP server is answering but the response is always emtpy. Neither `/entries?follow` nor `/entries?boot` displays any messages.

Is there anything else to do to enable gateway on CentOS7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give `read` permissions to user `systemd-journal-gateway` for file: `system.journal`

```
setfacl -m u:systemd-journal-gateway:r system.journal
```

If your `journald` is configured for persistent storage file `system.journal` should be in `/var/log/journal/{machine_id}/`. If above directory is missing
by default `journald` stores log data in `/run/log/journal/`.
For more info about configuring `journald` storage you can check this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I assumed `yum install` will do the right thing automatically.