# Monitoring systemd service activation times

Tags: systemd, services

I'd like to be able to retrieve from systemd how much time the last activation of a `oneshot` service took. I thought about the following options, but they didn't manage to convince me completely :

1. Compute `InactiveEnterTimestamp - InactiveExitTimestamp`, e.g. by reading them through the D-Bus interface in Python. This has the disadvantage of being inconsistent (=negative) while the service is running.
2. Use helper scripts in `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStartPost` to store a timestamp and compute the elapsed time once the service exits.
3. Use a wrapper script around the service executable that stores the elapsed time somewhere on the filesystem once the main executable exits.
4. Use an helper script in `ExecStartPost` that stores the value computed in #1.

My preference goes to #4 if possible, then #3 if not. What would you suggest? Is there a better way of doing this?

*Background: I am running [Tiny Tiny RSS](https://tt-rss.org), which has a feed updater script that I run at regular intervals using a systemd timer. I also run [Isync](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Isync) the same way to backup the contents of my Gmail inbox. My end goal is to be able to monitor how much time each service activation takes, and be alerted if it takes too long or hasn't run for a long time.*

EDIT: My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tiny Tiny RSS feeds update
After=network.target mysqld.service postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /usr/share/webapps/tt-rss/update.php --feeds
User=ttrss
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

And this is the timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tiny Tiny RSS feeds update timer

[Timer]
OnBootSec=1s
OnUnitInactiveSec=120s
Persistent=true
Unit=tt-rss.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compute InactiveEnterTimestamp - InactiveExitTimestamp

Activation time (in secs) is the result of:

```
(ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic - InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic) / 1e6
```

See the function `analyze_plot` in the file [analyze.c](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/analyze/analyze.c) for details.

But you should have [`RemainAfterExit=yes`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RemainAfterExit=) in your unit to get `ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic`.

You can calculate `ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic - ExecMainStartTimestampMonotonic` in the `PostStartExec` without `RemainAfterExit`.

> e.g. by reading them through the D-Bus interface in Python.

You can use `systemctl` to extract these values:

```
$ systemctl show -p InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic -p ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic unit
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=44364325621
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=44369331083
```

According to the [Interface Stability Promise](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InterfaceStabilityPromise/):

```
The stable interfaces are:

...

The command line interface of systemctl, loginctl, journalctl.
We will make sure that scripts invoking these commands will continue
to work with future versions of systemd. Note however that the output
generated by these commands is generally not included in the promise,
unless it is documented in the man page. Example: the output of
"systemctl status" is not stable, but the one of "systemctl show" is,
because the former is intended to be human readable and the latter
computer readable, and this is documented in the man page.
```

> My end goal is to be able to monitor how much time each service activation takes, and be alerted if it takes too long

You can set [TimeoutStartSec](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStartSec=) and [OnFailure](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#OnFailure=):

```
TimeoutStartSec= 

Configures the time to wait for start-up. If a daemon service does
not signal start-up completion within the configured time, the
service will be considered failed and will be shut down again.

OnFailure=

A space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when
this unit enters the "failed" state.
```

> or hasn't run for a long time

You can extract the last success time from the journal:

```
 journalctl -u your-service MESSAGE='Started your-service.service.'
```

But you should [enable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7) the persistent storage of log messages.

Comment: Re: Timeouts, I do not want my service to be killed once the timeout is reached, I just want to be warned so that I can take action (e.g. reduce feed update frequency) if that happens.

Comment: Re: Adding `RemainAfterExit=yes`: This prevents the timer from starting the service periodically, so I suppose I'm not supposed to use it that way?

Comment: I added my unit files to the question for reference.

Comment: Re: `systemctl show`: Is the output format supposed to be stable enough that I can parse it and use it?

Comment: And finally, thanks for the link to `analyze_plot`! I'll look into it a little bit later so I can see how it's used in real code by people that know what they are doing with systemd :)

Comment: @F.X., you can calculate `ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic - ExecMainStartTimestampMonotonic` in the `PostStartExec` without `RemainAfterExit`

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the tip! I think I'll add that in a separate `tt-rss.d` directory so that I can easily copy the same snippet to another service. Will post updates when I get that working.