# network trouble after upgrading from Debian Jessie to Stretch

Tags: debian, upgrade

I use a Lenovo U31-70 with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 Wireless Network Adapter using the `ath10k_pci` driver module.

I recently tried to upgrade my Jessie installation to Stretch by altering my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to the `stretch` repositories, and then running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. This ran for quite a while and got into a loop where the restart of `network-manager` timed out, and finally hanged my system hard enough to make it non-responsive.

After hard reboot, the system booted up and connected fine to my wifi, but running any `apt-get` operation finally ended up in the same state.

I decided to take drastic action; backed up my `/home` and installed Debian Stretch with non-free additions from scratch.

Now `apt-get` works fine, *but* the system won't shut down cleanly. Sometimes I will get a black screen with network operations trying to finish but never succeeding.

```
[*   ] (1 of 2) A stop job is running for Network Manager (4min 49s / 5min)
[*   ] (2 of 2) A stop job is running for WPA supplicant (5 min 2s / 6 min)
```

If I loose a network connection, I'm not able to re-establish it or switch to another network.

```
# service wpa_supplicant stop
```

takes about two minutes to return and so does

```
# service network_manager stop
```

Has anyone else experienced trouble with network managing in Stretch? Is there anything I can do about this?

The output of `ip a` is

```
...
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.0.17/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp320
    valid_lft 3450sec preferred_left 3450sec
  inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_left forever
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` is very short

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

and `/etc/network/interfaces.d` is an empty directory.

Comment: Did you have the same problem when using `su`? for example try `su -c 'ps -ef'`

Comment: @GAD3R Indeed I have not! With `su -c` both commands work fine. I'll try to capture the log next time this error appears.

Comment: Run the command `hostname` , let's say the output is Debian , as root edit your `/etc/hots` file by adding the following line on the top `127.0.0.1      Debian` (replace Debian with yours) logout then login then run some 
 command with `sudo`

Comment: @GAD3R Oh, wow, thanks! One problem down, another one to go! ;)

Comment: what is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`?

Comment: @GAD3R It says there is a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 Wireless Network adapter manager using the drive module `ath10k_pci`. Thank you for helping me find this info - I added it to the question.

Comment: So the first several paragraphs are just what you did before you wiped your system (and thus no longer relevant, save perhaps for the first paragraph with your hardware details), and your problem *now* is that if you lose your wireless network connection, then your system won't shut down and it just sits there waiting for Network Manager and friends to stop?

Comment: @GAD3R Ok, good suggestion, that seems to have changed things a little bit, but still network manager and WPA supplicant do not stop as expected.

Comment: There is an answer on U&L , please try it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297318/153195

Comment: @GAD3R Now they do stop, but not until after 50 seconds (the timeout limit keep increasing with 10 seconds whenever it runs out up until then). Then the system seems to shut down normally, but hangs in the end and eventually gets killed by the watchdog... I'm beginning to suspect this is a problem with power handling rather than with just the network...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well, not really. If I loose my connection, I can't get it to re-establish _and_ when I try to shut down Network manager & c:o are acting up. I think this is a problem with the network manager in Stretch, and I think that is also indicated by what happened during the upgrade attempt. (Which is why that info is still included.)