# NVIDIA Persistence Daemon stop job running for 5 minutes every time I shut down or restart PC

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, daemon

I've got Ubuntu 18.04, and every time I go to restart or shut down my computer, it takes forever. I pressed escape to see why, and there's a message every time saying

*"A stop job is running for NVIDIA Persistence Daemon (2min 35s / 4min 58s)"*, with the time counting up until it reaches 4 minutes 58 seconds, then it finally proceeds.

I do have a NVIDIA GTX 1060 card which otherwise seems to work normally.

How can I check to see what's causing this, and can I either reduce the countdown timer, or (preferably) fix the problem so the message goes away entirely?

Comment: `NVIDIA Persistence Daemon` is causing it.

Comment: A related question is of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310737/ .  And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273876/ covers much of the territory of diagnosis and reconfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been getting those from various causes over the last few years. 
 One solution, which seems to work generally, is to edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (as root/sudo) and uncomment the line

```
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=300s    # (for me it was 90s; whatever)
```

changing it to something like

```
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=20s
```

It seems like these "stop jobs" never complete.  It's a nuisance, especially when first setting up a system, when reboots tend to happen more.  You could make the timeout even shorter...  Setting it to 0s seems like it would be unsafe, but even 10s should be enough for NVIDIA to clean up, if it ever will.

That change won't take effect until you've rebooted (ironically).

Comment: It was already set to 90s oddly enough, not sure where it was getting the 5 minute timer from. But setting it to 20s seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: by default the value is 90, but the line is commented. So you first have to uncomment it