# Ubuntu using LXDE taking too long to shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, shutdown, lxde, display-manager

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and my desktop environment is LXDE. When I try to shutdown my computer the system keeps waiting and there is a message:

```
A stop job is running for Session c2 of user ... (1min 30s)
```

I've searched for this issue and encountered this thread: [A stop job is running for Session c2 of user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273876/a-stop-job-is-running-for-session-c2-of-user)

Following the second best answer, I've ran `journald` and looked for the application that was having trouble to exit. The relevant piece of log was:

```
jun 14 16:56:27 user systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
jun 14 16:57:54 user systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Stopping timed out. Killing.
jun 14 16:57:54 user systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Killing process 5306 (pcmanfm) with signal SIGKILL.
jun 14 16:57:54 user systemd[1]: session-c2.scope: Failed with result 'timeout'.
jun 14 16:57:54 user systemd[1]: Stopped Session c2 of user joao.
jun 14 16:57:54 user systemd[1]: Stopping Login Service...
```

For some reason the shutdown process isn't able to quit `pcmanfm`.

**Addition 1**: I know could just change `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s` as an workaround, but I wanted to actuallty really solve the problem.

**Addition 2**: I managed to stop gdbus by `systemctl stop gdbus`. Trying to now why `pcmanfm` won't quit now.