# Store messages from previous boots while keeping immediate log output

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

As [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159390/146335) suggests, the way to enable storing logs across boots is:

```
# mkdir /var/log/journal
# systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
# systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

But when I do it, it breaks the output of the `sudo journalctl -fu myservice` commands, because the messages aren't coming out immediately any more. `journalctl` just doesn't follow the log, and you have to restart journalctl.

Ubuntu 15.04, systemd 219-7ubuntu6. I saw a similar bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755062

Is that journalctl thing reliable?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that answer was not helpful.  According to the current man page, you can use SIGUSR1 instead

```
systemctl kill --signal=SIGUSR1 --kill-who=main systemd-journald.service
```

(exact command taken from `systemctl cat systemd-journal-flush.service`).

[Since then, systemd-journald was fixed upstream so that restarting it can no longer break the world](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6620#issuecomment-325942731)