# Can't see previous boot journal log

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I found that CentOS/Redhat will not store systemd-journal log to disk, Ubuntu will.

For CentOS/Redhat, each time I reboot, the journal log were removed ( it seems write to tmpfs only )

Why CentOS/Redhat don't want to keep journal log?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate, see: [How do I display log messages from previous boots under CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7)

**Why**

> By default, the journal stores log data in /run/log/journal/. Since /run/ is volatile, log data is lost at reboot. To make the data persistent, it is sufficient to create /var/log/journal/ where systemd-journald will then store the data.