# Armbian logs for previous boots

Tags: journalctl, armbian

I'm using armbian and have a problem with freezes on boot. I wanted to look into logs to understand why, but occasionaly I have only one log with current session:

```
journalctl --list-boots
```

returns only one boot.
I want to enable logging past boots too. I tried to do it like here is said:
[How do I display log messages from previous boots under CentOS 7?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159221/how-do-i-display-log-messages-from-previous-boots-under-centos-7)

But:

1. I already had /var/log/journal but it was empty.
2. After reboot I still have only one boot in list-boots.

What else can I do to enable logging?

Answer (score 2):

Did it by changing /etc/systemd/journald.conf to

```
...
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
...
```